# Node.js project working fine locally but not in the AWS Beanstalk, having Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium ENOENT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puppeteer, chromium, headless

I am trying to generate PDF using `node.js` and `puppeteer`. The code is working fine in the local windows machine. But when I am uploading my code into the AWS Beanstalk (Linux) I am having error message like:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium ENOENT\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n","locations":[{"line":3,"column":3}],"path":["exportAllProjectChangeStatus"],"extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}}],"data":{"exportAllProjectChangeStatus":null}}

I have installed `chromium` as a dependency in my local machine and also in the server. I am setting my puppeteer launch as following;

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
headless: true,
IgnoreHTTPSErrors: true,
executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',
args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--ignore-certificate-errors"],});
```

Can anybody please help me out to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is in the executablePath. To confirm, try running `which chromium` on the server, and pasting the result into `executablePath`

Answer (score 0):

Connect EC2 to ssh than run following command:-

cd home

cd webapp

cd .cache

cd puppeteer

cd chrome

cd linux-123.0.6312.58

cd chrome-linux64

after that run command:- **ldd chrome | grep not**
//this command check which dependencies are not installed

after than install following dependencies:- `sudo yum install -y alsa-lib.x86_64 atk.x86_64 cups-libs.x86_64 gtk3.x86_64 ipa-gothic-fonts libXcomposite.x86_64 libXcursor.x86_64 libXdamage.x86_64 libXext.x86_64 libXi.x86_64 libXrandr.x86_64 libXScrnSaver.x86_64 libXtst.x86_64 pango.x86_64 xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-fonts-cyrillic xorg-x11-fonts-misc xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-utils`